# How to get multiple variables within a single neat column?

Tags: linux, bash, columns, printf

I want to display a list like this:

```
        | A         | B         |
Item #1 | 291+4     | 56145+3   |
Item #2 | 7391+92   | 105+6067  |
```

but it looks like this:

```
        | A         | B         |
Item #1 | 291+4 | 56145+3 |
Item #2 | 7391+92 | 105+6067 |
```

with

```
listing variables example values

item_1_a="291"
item_1_a_diff="4"
item_1_b="56145"
item_1_b_diff="3"
item_2_a="7391"
item_2_a_diff="92"
item_2_b="105"
item_2_b_diff="6067"


for i in "${array[@]}"
do

    normally acquiring items values occurs here
    ...

    item_a="$item_1_a+$item_1_a_diff"
    item_b="$item_2_a+$item_2_a_diff"

    prinft "Item \#%s | %-9s | %-9s |" $i $item_a $item_b`

done
```

so the question is, how to get two variables neatly into a single column?

Comment: Welcome! could you post the array?

Comment: Are you reading this output into a variable in a shell script, or doing any kind of post-processing of the output before you display it?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you formatted each line with spaces instead of tabs.
by changing the line:

```
    prinft "Item \#%s | %-9s | %-9s |" $i $item_a $item_b`
```

to

```
    prinft "Item \#%s | %-9s\t| %-9s\t|" $i $item_a $item_b`
```

the columns should be aligned.
If the variables have wide difference length, and using tab still does not align the columns, consider using the command **column**.

Comment: The `%-9s` format allocates enough space for a 9 character long string. Not using tabs is not the issue.